# Build executable on Linux that does not depend on any shared libraries

Tags: linux, gcc

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04. gcc 4.8.2

I am working on a C++ console application. When I run "ldd" on the executable, I see the following:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe495e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9ffa754000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9ffa38e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9ffa087000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9ffaa6e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9ff9e71000
```

I am wondering if it is possible to define flags on gcc/linker such that the final executable does not depend on any shared libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `-static` while linking :-)

Static linking should be avoided not only for security reasons.

BTW: As I know there is no way to create a static lib from a dynamic one. So if you have only the shared lib, you can't link static.

Comment: Doesn't this require statically built libraries to be available though?

Comment: This needs the appropriate libs on the build machine during linking, but no other libs while executing.

Comment: And this has some downsides. Applications using [NSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) - practically speaking, network applications - should better be dynamically linked. See [nnswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)

Comment: If OP's feeling particularly adventurous he can build his own static libraries ;)  But again, there needs to be a really good reason for it.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. This executable needs to run when the hard-disk or the OS becomes unstable. Our goal is that it doesn't depend on any shared libraries.